# Tips styling nouislider with bootstrap css

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, nouislider

I am trying to format the noUi tooltips to follow the bootstrap design. But I Fail and wonder if it is possible in any easy way.

I tried to format the markup according to bootstraps template found here:

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/tooltips/#markup

> HTML

```
<!-- Generated markup by the plugin -->
<div class="tooltip tooltip-top" role="tooltip">
  <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
  <div class="tooltip-inner">
    Some tooltip text!
  </div>
</div>
```

> Javascript

```
// by changing the noUislider.js function  "addTooltip"
function addTooltip ( handle, handleNumber ) {
    if ( !options.tooltips[handleNumber] ) {
        return false;
    }
    let deg =addNodeTo(handle.firstChild, 'tooltip');
    addClass(deg,'tooltip-top');
    addNodeTo(deg, "tooltip-arrow");
    return addNodeTo(deg, 'tooltip-inner');
    //return addNodeTo(handle.firstChild, options.cssClasses.tooltip);
}
```

which generate a template but won't show any tooltip at all. So I am probably missing something critical. If I only add 'tooltip-top' I get a visible black tooltip but it is way to small and garbled.

Comment: Check that you have the newest version, check that you include all the JS (in the order jQuery, PopperJs, BootstrapJs). Also check the current docs, you are referencing the old docs. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/

Comment: Thanks I have checked. I manage to activate the bs tooltip using the following java script: 

slider.on('slide',function(value){ $('#slider [data-handle="0"]').attr('data-original-title', value).tooltip('show').tooltip('update') });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how my solution ended up using bootstrap to tooltips on noUIslider and styling the slider handle using boootstrap css.

```
slideDIM.on('update', function(value) {
    $.getq('queue', '/dim/' +  value[0].replace('%', ''));
    $('#slider-dimmer [data-handle="0"]').attr('data-original-title', value).tooltip('show').tooltip('update')
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#slider-dimmer [data-handle="0"]').tooltip('hide');
        }, 3000);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8snj9t93/7/

Dragging works but tapping the slider will currently look good so I have disabled that.